# ServiceStack CredentialsAuthProvider - appSettings authRealm oAuthProvider

Tags: c#, servicestack

I am playing with the Auth Plugin `CredentialsAuthProvider`. It askes for 3 parameters at creation, `appSettings`, `authRealm`, and `oAuthProvider`. I can't find the explanation of this API on the wiki page https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Authentication-and-authorization

Could you please explain to me what each parameter does? How do they affect the `CredentialsAuthProvider` that I am creating?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off you don't need to provide these. There is an empty CredentialsAuthProvider constructor you can use for basic authentication.

**authRealm** is the name of the realm used for the WWW-Authenticate header in HTTP Basic Authentication. Usually the name of your server. It can be used by clients to help manage passwords. It ends up looking like this:

```
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="My Server"
```

**OAuth Settings**

**appSettings** is just a way to access settings usually in the web.config mostly for OAuth. For example here are the settings for facebook OAuth pulled from the SocialBootstrapApi project.

- oauth.facebook.AppId
- oauth.facebook.AppSecret
- oauth.facebook.RedirectUrl
- oauth.facebook.CallbackUrl

In this example **oAuthProvider** is the string "facebook" It is simply a key to allow multiple OAuth providers in your settings.

See https://github.com/ServiceStack/SocialBootstrapApi/blob/master/src/SocialBootstrapApi/Web.config#L24 for lots of app settings examples and different OAuth providers.

Comment: 'authRealm' is particularly interesting to me. "It can be used by clients to help manage passwords" Could you give me an example on how to do it? Thanks.

Comment: For example web browsers can retain and re-use your authentication information. They can re-use your provided credentials for resources in the same realms.